# Why is the baked normal map more accentuated in some parts?

Tags: baking

This one in particular is more accentuated in the middle:

[image: screen capture showing normal map and partial shader nodes]

Why does this happen and how do I make it uniform? I've baked a normal map for the leather part and it didn't happen, as you can see.

Comment: hello, what do you mean by more accentuated? could you please hightlight the part you're talking about?

Comment: The part in the middle of the guard is harsher than the rest, as you can see. Pre-baked it doesn't look like this.

Comment: it's hard to say, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I recalculated outside normals and applied location & rotation (before baking) and it's fine now.